# Append script to page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I receive on data (after an ajax call)  2 script tags, which I get from data like this:

```
var scripts = $(data).filter('script');
```

Now I want to append the content of this 2 script tags to a div. How can I do this?

```
for(var i=0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    $('#myDiv').append(scripts[i]);
}
```

The above approach doesn't append anything.

I can't reconstruct the scripts in js (I've seen this approach in other posts) because my scripts contain loads of elements and logic.

Comment: Please post your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function codeGenerate(code){
    var JS= document.createElement('script');
    JS.text= code;
    document.body.appendChild(JS);
}
```